# Strange issue on graphical layout and on runtime

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, view

Now I am just creating a simple page. However nothing pops out except for the first textview.

[Graphical layout Image](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/210/deletein10.png/)

[Emulator Image](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/849/deletein10.png/)

I tried to clean via project>clean. It's strange this only happened on this xml. Others seem to work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        >
    <TextView 
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" 
      android:text="Background Color: "/>

    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/Spinner"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        >    
    <TextView 

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:text="Size: "        />

    <RadioGroup 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <RadioButton 
            android:id="@+id/small"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Small"
            />
        <RadioButton 
            android:id="@+id/medium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Medium"
            />
        <RadioButton 
            android:id="@+id/large"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Large"
            />

    </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Make_Changes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Confirm"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry guys about long xml code I really don't like posting something like this on stackoverflow but I really I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you have "match_parent" everywhere :)
Try layout_width="wrap_content" and layout_height="wrap_content" for all except parent LinearLayout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        >
    <TextView 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:text="Background Color: "/>

    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/Spinner"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        >    
    <TextView 

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Size: "        />

    <RadioGroup 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <RadioButton 
            android:id="@+id/small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Small"
            />
        <RadioButton 
            android:id="@+id/medium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium"
            />
        <RadioButton 
            android:id="@+id/large"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large"
            />

    </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Make_Changes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Confirm"/>

</LinearLayout>
```